# съезжает MDBottomNavigationItem

Tags: python, kivy

Есть код в кв файле:

```
    MDBottomNavigation:

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "screen 1"

            Button:
                text:
                    'screen1'

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "screen 2"

            Button:
                text:
                    'screen2'

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "screen 3"

            Button:
                text:
                    'screen3'
```

При вызове кнопки слайд должен изменяться на MDBottomNavigation. Он изменяется, но криво. Помогите решить проблему. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fyz0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Для начала попробуй переустановить библиотеку из мастер ветки:

```
python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall git+https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD.git
```

Вроде, пофиксили эту ошибку. Если не поможет, то после открытия экрана с вкладками выполни метод `refresh_tabs` - https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/uix/bottomnavigation.py#L585